# Android app ignore headphone dock (temporarily) to use voice search

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, android-audiomanager, android-debug

I am writing an android app that allows a phone to be plugged into a speaker dock, such as SonrLabs, Bose etc, but when they press a button, still be able to voice search from the phone microphone without unplugging the phone from the dock every time they want to do a speaking search.

Does anyone know how I can temporarily override the headphone controls so that the phone thinks it isn't connected to headphones, and will do a voice search normally. Or if this is even possible?

I really just need to know if I can do a normal voice search from the phone microphone while headphones are plugged into the phone.

Thanks!

Comment: By "headphone", do you mean "headset"? If the dock is indeed detected as a headphone (i.e. something without a microphone) then the problem has solved itself. If it's detected as a headset I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: I guess I am not sure, thanks for pointing out the difference. I think headset because when I click the voice search button, it tries to listen for something, but nothing I say is heard. It always comes up with no results. Is there a way I could change it so the phone thinks it a headphone?